# what "bear out" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

This is a part of an online article titled "Why do gamers like RGB Lights?" (RGB lights are the lights installed in gaming keyboards that illuminate the keys and make them visible in darkness)

> So what’s the deal? Why do so many gamers and gaming brands salivate over the idea of embedding RGB LED bulbs on their mice, keyboards, headsets and even speakers?
>
> According to Dr Marcus Carter, Senior Lecturer in Digital Cultures at The University of Sydney, the answer **is borne out** of both practicality on the part of manufacturers and a sense of pride on the part of consumers.

"bear out" (Oxford dictionary def)
support or confirm something.
"this assumption is not borne out by any evidence"

but support or confirm doesn't seem to fit here.

Comment: Omitted context: article in 'PC World Australia', 16 June 2020. Seems to be a clear misuse of 'borne out of'. I would have edited that to 'the answer is practicality on the part of manufacturers, and a sense of pride on the part of consumers.' Don't expect great writing in computer magazines.

Answer (score 1):

This is partly mis-parsing the sentence, and partly bad writing.  This isn't the phrasal verb **to bear out**; the writer is simply saying that this behavior is born *from*, or *out of* these things.

You can tell that this isn't the phrasal verb *to bear out* because that verb never uses *of*.  We would say  "This conclusion is borne out *by* the evidence", but never "borne out *of*".

But it is bad writing because it *looks* like "to bear out", and it isn't, which makes the sentence confusing, and because the writer has used *borne* incorrectly.  If they meant "given birth to", they should have used *born*, because *borne* almost always means "carried" in a fairly literal sense.  This looks like a writer trying to write like how they think smart people write!

Reference: [The Difference Between 'Born' and 'Borne'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/borne-vs-born-difference-usage-spelling)